# Passing variables to ren command in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Can someone show me what is wrong with this syntax? I simply cannot get this to work:

```
#there is file called MyLog.log inside'logoutput'
$file='myimage'
$LogsDestFolder='logoutput'
Write-Host "Renaming log for $file.bmp"
ren $LogsDestFolder\MyLog.log $LogsDestFolder\$file.log
```

It keeps complaining I cannot pass variables inside the 'ren' command. I tried put single or double quotes, nothing worked.

Keep getting this:

> ren : Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path
> or device name.

Thanks!

Comment: Never seen the 'cannot pass variables' error, but you shouldn't be passing a path to the second argument to Rename-Item.  Try `ren "$LogsDestFolder\MyLog.log" "$file.log"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is most likely that you are passing a path into the parameter `-NewName`. Your command translates to this currently:

```
Rename-Item -Path $LogsDestFolder\MyLog.log -NewName $LogsDestFolder\$file.log
```

`ren` = `Rename-Item` which you can see from `Get-Alias ren`. The actual error I get when I run this is:

> ren : Cannot rename because the target specified represents a path or device name.

If you look at [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849763.aspx) for `Rename-Item` you will see under the description for `-NewName`

> Specifies the new name of the item. Enter only a name, not a path and name. If you enter a path that is different from the path that is specified in the Path parameter, Rename-Item generates an error.

There is no need to set the path for the NewName since you already did that with `-Path`. Remove the path component and leave the file name like Ryan suggested.

```
Rename-Item -Path "$LogsDestFolder\MyLog.log" -NewName "$file.log"
#or
Ren "$LogsDestFolder\MyLog.log" "$file.log"
```

Always a good idea to put paths in quotes. You need to in this case anyway to prevent a parsing error.